# Fourier inversion formula on locally compact abelian groups.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I am learning of abstract Fourier analysis for the first time and I am having trouble seeing the Fourier inversion formula. It seems like it should not be so hard to prove.

Let $f \in L^1(G)$ where $G$ is locally compact abelian group and consider it's Haar measure. Then we define the Fourier transform of $f$ as:
$$\hat{f}(\chi)=\int_{G}f(g)\overline{\chi(g)}$$
Now the Fourier inversion is:
$$f(g)=\int_{\hat{G}}\hat{f}(\chi)\chi(g)$$
where the integral is over the haar measure of $\hat{G}$. I feel like this formula should be easy to prove somehow using Fubini and "Haar"-ness. But I was not able to figure it out.

As a side note: what does it mean that $\hat{f}$ vanishes over infinity? $G$ might not have a norm so what does infinity mean in this context?

Comment: The image of the Fourier transform on $L^1$-functions does not have a simple description, even on the real line. If you want an inversion formula then you need to have a definite target space in mind: $L^2$ to $L^2$, Schwartz space to Schwartz space, and $L^1$ to ???

Comment: You are an optimist! :)  It is highly non-trivial to prove this... though by now it is "standard". Anyway, "vanishing at (!) infinity" for a complex-valued function on a topological space means that, for every $\epsilon>0$, there is a compact subset $K$ such that $|f(x)|<\epsilon$ for $x\not\in K$.

Comment: Vanishing at $\infty$ on a locally compact (Hausdorff) space means being less than $\varepsilon$ outside some compact subset (depending on $\varepsilon$).

Comment: @KCd I thought the Fourier transform of an L1 function is continuous, is that not true? I apologize for my ignorance.

Comment: Yes, but nobody is claiming all continuous functions vanishing at $\infty$ are Fourier transforms of $L^1$- functions! A mapping $f:A\to B$ is not invertible just because you know the values are in $B$.